# Changing Multiple classes of a tr (HTML/JQUERY)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have mutiple

Im tryting to change them with:

```
function changetr(e) {
if(e.className == 'tropen') {
    e.className = 'trclose';
} else {
    e.className = 'tropen';
}
}

function changetd(e) {
if(e.className == 'poolclose') {
    e.className = 'poolopen';
} else {
    e.className = 'poolclose';
}
}
```

I have an onchange on a image: onclick="changetd(pool1); changetr(subpool1);"

But it only changes one tr or td, i would like to update all the tr's or td's with that value.

Hope anyone has a solution, since im pretty new to jquery.

Example:

```html
<table>
  <!-- Pool open-->
  <tbody>
    <tr class="tropen">
      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="poolclose" id="poolid2" colspan="2" onclick="changetd(poolid2); changetr(subpool2);"></td>
                      <td>Test pool 2015</td>
                    </tr>


                    <!-- Subpool open-->
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <table>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <table>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr class="trclose" id="subpool2">
                              <td>
                                <table>
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="12"></td>
                                      <td class="poolclose" id="subpoolid1" onclick="changetd(substitute1); changetr(subpoolid1);"></td>
                                      <td class="pooltext">test</td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>

                                <!-- Invallers -->
                                <table>
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td>
                                        <table>
                                          <tbody>
                                            <tr class="trclose" id="substitute1">
                                              <td>
                                                <table>
                                                  <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                      <td width="26"></td>
                                                      <td class="poolclose" id="substituteid1" onclick="changetd(substituteid1); changetr(substitutelist1);"></td>
                                                      <td class="pooltext">Dit is een invaller</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                  </tbody>
                                                </table>

                                                <!-- invaller overzicht -->
                                                <table>
                                                  <tbody>
                                                    <tr class="trclose" id="substitutelist1">
                                                      <td>
                                                        <table>
                                                          <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                              <td width="40"></td>
                                                              <td class="substitutelist" id="substitutelistid1"></td>
                                                              <td>Dit is een lijst met invallers</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                          </tbody>
                                                        </table>

                                                      </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                  </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                              </td>
                                            </tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        <!--Invallers close-->

                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <!--Subpool close-->

                        <!-- Add a new record if there was no subpool to begin the while loop-->
                        <table>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                <table>
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr class="trclose" id="subpool2">
                                      <td>
                                        <table>
                                          <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td width="12"></td>
                                              <td class="poolplus"></td>
                                              <td class="pooltext">
                                                <form action="/poolbeheer/poolonderdeel" method="post">
                                                  <input type="hidden" name="poolid" value="2">
                                                  <input type="text" name="subpoolname" required="">
                                                  <input type="submit" value="Poolonderdeel Koppelen">
                                                </form>
                                              </td>
                                            </tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <!--Subpool close-->

                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!--Pool close-->

    <!-- Pool open-->
    <tr class="tropen">
      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="poolclose" id="poolid1" colspan="2" onclick="changetd(poolid1); changetr(subpool1);"></td>
                      <td>Test Pool</td>
                    </tr>


                    <!-- Subpool open-->
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <table>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <table>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr class="trclose" id="subpool1">
                              <td>
                                <table>
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="12"></td>
                                      <td class="poolclose" id="subpoolid2" onclick="changetd(substitute2); changetr(subpoolid2);"></td>
                                      <td class="pooltext">test 2</td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>

                                <!-- Invallers -->
                                <table>
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td>
                                        <table>
                                          <tbody>
                                            <tr class="trclose" id="substitute2">
                                              <td>
                                                <table>
                                                  <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                      <td width="26"></td>
                                                      <td class="poolclose" id="substituteid1" onclick="changetd(substituteid1); changetr(substitutelist1);"></td>
                                                      <td class="pooltext">Dit is een invaller</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                  </tbody>
                                                </table>

                                                <!-- invaller overzicht -->
                                                <table>
                                                  <tbody>
                                                    <tr class="trclose" id="substitutelist1">
                                                      <td>
                                                        <table>
                                                          <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                              <td width="40"></td>
                                                              <td class="substitutelist" id="substitutelistid1"></td>
                                                              <td>Dit is een lijst met invallers</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                          </tbody>
                                                        </table>

                                                      </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                  </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                              </td>
                                            </tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        <!--Invallers close-->

                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <!--Subpool close-->

                        <!-- Add a new record if there was no subpool to begin the while loop-->
                        <table>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                <table>
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr class="trclose" id="subpool1">
                                      <td>
                                        <table>
                                          <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td width="12"></td>
                                              <td class="poolplus"></td>
                                              <td class="pooltext">
                                                <form action="/poolbeheer/poolonderdeel" method="post">
                                                  <input type="hidden" name="poolid" value="1">
                                                  <input type="text" name="subpoolname" required="">
                                                  <input type="submit" value="Poolonderdeel Koppelen">
                                                </form>
                                              </td>
                                            </tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <!--Subpool close-->

                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!--Pool close-->

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is an error prone solution as additional classes on the element will cause it to fail. Use jQuery and `toggleClass()` instead.

Comment: Please show an example of your HTML too if you want a working suggestion :)

Comment: Added an example :) removed some extra lines so the tables do not close properly and did not include the php for the while loops just marked them while so that it shows the logic

Comment: Please show the output HTML (as saved from the browser). Not everyone can mentally compile PHP :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("table td").click(function() {
       $("table td").toggleClass('tdopen tdclose');
    });
});
```

```css
.tropen{
  background-color: red;
}

.trclose{
  background-color: blue;
}
.tdopen{
  background-color: red;
}

.tdclose{
  background-color: blue;
}
table{
border: 1px solid;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="tropen">
    <td class="tdopen">text text text</td>
    <td class="tdclose">text text text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tropen">
    <td class="tdopen">text text</td>
    <td class="tdclose">text text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tropen">
    <td class="tdopen">text</td>
    <td class="tdclose">text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: And how can i make your code work with an id (of the tr or td that has to change) im giving the function?